# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() method wont work

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Iam having problem deserialzing a json string to a .net list object. It worked for a while and suddenly it stopted for some reason. See the link for error message

https://gyazo.com/f6ef55625ffa94060cfc900542c24e0f

the json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "project": {
  "id": 797100,
  "client_id": 339652,
  "name": "Internal LWA",
  "code": "",
  "active": false,
  "billable": false,
  "bill_by": "none",
  "hourly_rate": null,
  "budget": null,
  "budget_by": "none",
  "notify_when_over_budget": false,
  "over_budget_notification_percentage": 80,
  "over_budget_notified_at": null,
  "show_budget_to_all": false,
  "created_at": "2010-08-13T14:15:36Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-03-24T13:59:07Z",
  "starts_on": "2010-08-09",
  "ends_on": null,
  "estimate": null,
  "estimate_by": "none",
  "hint_earliest_record_at": "2010-08-09",
  "hint_latest_record_at": "2012-04-13",
  "notes": "I största möjliga mån bör all tid försöka knytas till kundprojekt. Övrig tid rapporteras här.",
  "cost_budget": null,
  "cost_budget_include_expenses": false
}
  },
  {
     "project": {
      "id": 805512,
      "client_id": 344217,
  "name": "Skräddarsydd analys",
  "code": "143-20100505",
  "active": false,
  "billable": true,
  "bill_by": "none",
  "hourly_rate": null,
  "budget": null,
  "budget_by": "project_cost",
  "notify_when_over_budget": true,
  "over_budget_notification_percentage": 80,
  "over_budget_notified_at": null,
  "show_budget_to_all": true,
  "created_at": "2010-08-20T14:52:11Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-03-24T13:59:07Z",
  "starts_on": "2010-08-09",
  "ends_on": null,
  "estimate": null,
  "estimate_by": "project_cost",
  "hint_earliest_record_at": "2010-08-09",
  "hint_latest_record_at": "2010-08-19",
  "notes": "Unik flödesanalys som besvarar frågorna: Vem köper, varför köper inte vissa och lite annat som vi är experter på.",
  "cost_budget": 50000,
  "cost_budget_include_expenses": true
}
```

},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your model?
It seems that 'updated_at' property is a int instead of DateTime or Nullable DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be tricky but you should try check if you're not getting another unit type... I see some non-secure variables where can be error. You should make sure that you always get the same data types... like old variable can be type of integer and new variable can be type of double or string or whatever. Because it's looks like that this can be your case. I suggest to you instead of your class try to use this one and let me know :)

```
public class Project
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string client_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string active { get; set; }
    public string billable { get; set; }
    public string bill_by { get; set; }
    public object hourly_rate { get; set; }
    public object budget { get; set; }
    public string budget_by { get; set; }
    public bool notify_when_over_budget { get; set; }
    public string over_budget_notification_percentage { get; set; }
    public object over_budget_notified_at { get; set; }
    public bool show_budget_to_all { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string starts_on { get; set; }
    public object ends_on { get; set; }
    public object estimate { get; set; }
    public string estimate_by { get; set; }
    public string hint_earliest_record_at { get; set; }
    public string hint_latest_record_at { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public string? cost_budget { get; set; }
    public bool cost_budget_include_expenses { get; set; }
}
```